# How to avoid CSS styles to be applied for particular element

Tags: html, css

I am using `<hr />` element in my HTML. In Bootstrap.css file they applied some styles to `<hr />` tags. I don't want to apply those styles to one of my `<hr />` tag. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you show us the CSS and HTML?

Comment: Override the applied styles for that particular element.

Comment: You can customize your bootstrap...

Comment: But I need those styles for other hr elements, I just want to avoid it to perticular hr tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have an id to the div enclosing the hr

```
<div id="hrDiv">
   <hr>
</div>
```

To remove style you can use removeAttr property over the selector

```
$("#hrDiv hr").removeAttr("style");
```

If you are not using inline style then you need to override the propeties in css

```
#hrVid hr
{
//oveeride property
}
```

You can also put id to hr tag directly

Comment: The style is applied via css from the stylesheet, not inline. The style attribute will be empty already.

Comment: Then you can override the css properties using selector #hrDiv hr

Comment: Without knowing more about OP's markup, why put the id on the parent div and not the hr?

Comment: You can also do that but i usually avoid it for good practice sake.

Comment: How is adding new markup better practice than applying a class to an element you actually want to style? It's just bloat that can break the structure of a page, I don't see any benefits.

Answer (score 1):

Simply override the styles.

Say bootstrap applies:

```
hr{ border: 1px solid red; padding: 10px; }
```

In a stylesheet declared *after* bootstrap, override then like this:

```
hr{ border: none; padding: 0; }
```

Edited addition:

Based on the replies, if it's a particular HR tag (but not all), give the specific one a class:

```
<hr class="specialHr" />
```

And apply the style:

```
hr.specialHr{ border: none; padding: 0; }
```

Comment: But I need those styles for other hr elements, I just want to avoid it to perticular hr tag

Answer (score 1):

You can set a class to your `<hr/>` and apply different styles to it. Or use the css :not() selector.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that.

You have to override every CSS property explicitly.

You can also modify your css file to create a class (instead of applying the style to all tags). However, you must explicitly declare this class in each `<hr>` tag where you want to apply the style (inverted your problem)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you edit the Bootstrap CSS so that you need to add a class in order to get the BootStrap styling e.g. `<hr class="hr">`

```
hr.hr {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #eee;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    height: 0;
}
```

You can also create a class that specify the default styling to override Bootstrap. The default styling can differ from different browsers so I guess you need to decide which one  to use. I took this from the user agent stylesheet in Chrome.

```
hr.hr {
    display: block;
    -webkit-margin-before: 0.5em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 0.5em;
    -webkit-margin-start: auto;
    -webkit-margin-end: auto;
    border-style: inset;
    border-width: 1px;
}
```

If you take that and make a CSS style rule specifying the same appearance you could mimic the default styling for that browser.

Answer (score 0):

Just create an individual style for the `<hr>` tag.

So for example, to make the `<hr>` 500 pixels wide use:

```
<hr style="width:500px;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

at the end of your tag override with !important

example

```
<hr style="width:200px" !important>
```

this will overide with your changes

Comment: Inline css is defined in markup (rather than js that animates for example) is considered quite bad practice (since it breaks separation of concerns). !important can also be easily abused, and this isn't a case to use it. Check out http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

Answer (score 0):

There are few approaches... 
Give this particular < hr /> a class (or id) and add your styles in your css:

```
 <hr class="myspecialhr" />
<style>     
 .myspecialhr {height:5px;}
</style>
```

You could also add you style overrides inline with the element:

```
 <hr style ="height:5px;"/>
```

You could "tag" this < hr /> with the class or id of a parent item of that particular page.

```
 <div class ="page1">
  <hr />
 </div>
 <style>
  .page1 hr {height:5px;}
 </style>
```

Finally, you could use CSS borders to achieve your layout goals and replace the

---

in your pages.

Answer (score 0):

If this is something bigger than `<hr>` and you need to un-use many styles, you can put the contents in `<iframe>`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this now:

```css
hr {
  all: reset;
}
```